# Wifi/Bluetooth/Ethernet all mixed up in Sys Prefs

Tags: macos, wifi, bluetooth

Today took my iMac out of sleep (9,1) and it was not loading anything over the internet.  So I looked into it, and noticed my wifi indicator has gone missing from my menu bar.

So I looked further into it, and as per the following screenshot my wireless is showing with the ethernet icon, my ethernet does not exist, my bluetooth is showing the wifi logo and appears to be connecting over PAN to one of my Airport Extreme access points - I am totally confused.  I have rebooted, turned wifi on and off, and it's staying the same.  Currently doing a software update to see what happens, and internet is working again as I am currently connected with this exact setup as per the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

It looks like it's just a naming mixup, like a bodged plist or something for the network connection names, I have turned bluetooth off and it stays connected.  Anyone got a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [some other users](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12932825#12932825), you can delete the icons and OS X will re-assign them automatically.

Very strange behavior thought!

Comment: Close, I deleted the connections, and rebooted hoping it would add them back for me, but there were still non left on the restart, so I manually re-added each type that I need and now it's back to normal.  Very confusing.  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, very confusing indeed. I've never seen this before!